# failed in install Cinnamon - held broken packages

Tags: cinnamon, mint

I am trying to install Cinnamon and allow myself to choose which one I would prefer. I have done the first two main steps.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

which were both successful and then I try to run.

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

and this is what I get -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinnamon : Depends: gir1.2-muffin-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcogl5 (>= 1.7.4) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmuffin0 (>= 1.0.0-0ubuntu1~precise) but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: gnome-themes-standard but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: gnome-session-fallback but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the PPA you are trying  to use and use the Cinnamon's official PPA for Ubuntu.

https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable

I got the above link to the ppa by visiting [Cinnamon's Download Page](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?page_id=61)

I would assume that the unofficial PPA you are trying to use is having some problems.

I *had* Cinnamon installed from the official PPA so I know that it was working as of April or May...

to use the official PPA(instructions from the [PPA's Download page](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-stable))

```
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

If you want to try to use the unoffical PPA you were trying to use you can try to fix the broken packages via `sudo apt-get install -f`

To remove the old PPA via the command line run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove  ppa:merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa
```

It will promt you just like it did when you added it,  press `Enter` to remove.

You can also remove it via the **Software Sources** in the **edit** menu of the Software Center or the **Setting** button of the Update Manager if you want to do it with a GUI.
Just click on the **Other Software** tab on the Software Sources window and highlight the PPA(the name is at the end of the line) and then click the **Remove** button.

After using any of the above methods you will need to run `sudo apt-get update` again to complete the removal

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into that now, am I able to remove the old PPA is loaded?

Comment: yes you can remove the old PPa, I will edit my answer to include that information...Sorry I should have done that in the first place...